# HandleTime calculation Using Oracle Analytical Functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have my table as below.

```
create table AuditInfo
  (AuditID number(5),
   TaskID number(5),
   Task_Status varchar2(15),
   UserID number(5),
   SegmentTime number(5));

insert into AuditInfo values(1,101,'ASSIGNED',1,0);
insert into AuditInfo values(2,101,'HOLD',1,5);
insert into AuditInfo values(3,101,'RESERVED',1,0);
insert into AuditInfo values(4,101,'ASSIGNED',1,0);
insert into AuditInfo values(5,101,'COMPLETED',1,5);
insert into AuditInfo values(6,102,'ASSIGNED',1,0);
insert into AuditInfo values(7,102,'HOLD',1,5);
insert into AuditInfo values(8,102,'TRANSFER',2,0);
insert into AuditInfo values(9,102,'ASSIGNED',2,0);
insert into AuditInfo values(10,102,'HOLD',2,5);
insert into AuditInfo values(11,102,'COMPLETED',2,0);
```

I need an extra column Task_Handle_Time for each task at the end of its life cycle

1) A task with status TRANSFER or COMPLETED is treated as end of life cyle.

2) If a task contains both TRANSFER(User Transfer)) or COMPLETED then need to calculate Handle time separatly for each life cycle. TaskID 102 represents this scenario.

3) Total Handle time is Sum of Segment of a task starting from ASSIGNED status to its life cycle status(TRANSFER,COMPLETED).

My Output should look like

```
AuditID TaskID  Task_Status UserID  SegmentTime  HandleTime

1        101    ASSIGNED    1       0            0

2        101    HOLD        1       5            0

3        101    RESERVED    1       0            0

4        101    ASSIGNED    1       0            0

5        101    COMPLETED   1       5            10

6        102    ASSIGNED    1       0            0

7        102    HOLD        1       5            0  

8        102    TRANSFER    2       0            5

9        102    ASSIGNED    2       0            0

10       102    HOLD        2       5            0

11       102    COMPLETED   2       0            5
```

In above output for Task 101 there is no User Transfer and Handle time is calculated once with all sum of all segment times and for
Task 102 there is User Transfer from UserID 1 to 2 so we should calculate HandleTime twice for each life cyle.

Here is my Query which doesnt work as needed

```
select ai.*, case when row_number() over(partition by TaskID,Task_Status in(TRANSFER,COMPLETED) order by TaskID)=count(*) over(partition by TaskID,Task_Status in(TRANSFER,COMPLETED) order by TaskID)
then sum(SegmentTime) over(partition by TaskID,Task_Status in(TRANSFER,COMPLETED) order by TaskID) else 0 end as "Handle Time" from AuditInfo ai order by AuditID;
```

Is there a way to achive this?

Here is the SQL Fiddle link that i have tried.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d96d/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does the trick - key is to use Oracle's sum() analytic function as a running-total over 0's for normal rows and "1" for the transition row.  That allows you to compartmentalize rows that fit between two transitions.  A little cleanup to deal with the off-by-one error of that approach, and you're golden:

```
SELECT  AUDITID, TASKID, TASK_STATUS, USERID, 
        DECODE(RUNTOT,GRP,0,SUM(SEGMENTTIME) OVER (PARTITION BY TASKID, GRP)) HANDLING 
FROM (
    SELECT  A.*, 
            NVL(LAG(RUNTOT) OVER (PARTITION BY TASKID ORDER BY AUDITID) , RUNTOT) GRP 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT  A.*, 
                SUM(CASE WHEN TASK_STATUS IN ('TRANSFER', 'COMPLETED') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                        OVER (PARTITION BY TASKID ORDER BY AUDITID) RUNTOT
        FROM AUDITINFO A) A)
ORDER BY AUDITID ASC

AUDITID TASKID TASK_STATUS     USERID HANDLING                               
1       101    ASSIGNED        1      0                                      
2       101    HOLD            1      0                                      
3       101    RESERVED        1      0                                      
4       101    ASSIGNED        1      0                                      
5       101    COMPLETED       1      10                                     
6       102    ASSIGNED        1      0                                      
7       102    HOLD            1      0                                      
8       102    TRANSFER        2      5                                      
9       102    ASSIGNED        2      0                                      
10      102    HOLD            2      0                                      
11      102    COMPLETED       2      5
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be just a simple sum() and not a convoluted nested analytic functions to achieve with a proper data model. Here's a direction you could take.

```
create table Task ( 
   TaskID      number(5)      primary key 
);
create table TaskCycle ( 
   CycleID     number(5)      primary key,
   TaskId      number(5)      not null references Task (TaskID)
);
create table CycleSegment (
   SegmentID   number(5)      primary key,
   CycleID     number(5)      not null references TaskCycle (CycleID),
   Task_Status varchar2(15)   not null,
   UserID      number(5)      not null,
   SegmentTime number(5)      not null 
);

insert into Task values (101);
insert into Task values (102);

insert into TaskCycle values ( 1, 101 );
insert into TaskCycle values ( 2, 102 );
insert into TaskCycle values ( 3, 102 );

insert into CycleSegment values ( 1, 1, 'ASSIGNED', 1, 0 );
insert into CycleSegment values ( 2, 1, 'HOLD', 1, 5);
insert into CycleSegment values ( 3, 1, 'RESERVED', 1, 0);
insert into CycleSegment values ( 4, 1, 'ASSIGNED', 1, 0);
insert into CycleSegment values ( 5, 1, 'COMPLETED', 1, 5);
insert into CycleSegment values ( 6, 2, 'ASSIGNED', 1, 0);
insert into CycleSegment values ( 7, 2, 'HOLD', 1, 5);
insert into CycleSegment values ( 8, 2, 'TRANSFER', 2, 0);
insert into CycleSegment values ( 9, 3, 'ASSIGNED', 2, 0);
insert into CycleSegment values ( 10, 3, 'HOLD', 2, 5);
insert into CycleSegment values ( 11, 3, 'COMPLETED', 2, 0);

select s.SegmentID, c.TaskID, s.Task_Status, s.UserID, s.SegmentTime
     , case 
          when s.Task_Status in ('TRANSFER', 'COMPLETED')
          then
             ( select sum(s2.SegmentTime)
                 from CycleSegment s2
                where s2.CycleID = c.CycleID )
          else 0
       end as Handle_Time
  from TaskCycle c
  join CycleSegment s on (s.CycleID = c.CycleID )
 order by c.TaskID, s.SegmentID
;
```